# Remote object call inside remote JVM

Tags: java, weblogic, jndi

I'm working with weblogic Server. I was wondering if after binding an object in the JNDI context it would be possible to make remote call on this object (executing it inside the remote JVM).

In my local JVM:

```
Context ctx = null;
Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"t3://remoteServer:7001/);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,"");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,"");

try {
  ctx = new InitialContext(env);
  MyObjectImpl obj1 = new MyObjectImpl();
  ctx.bind("jndi_name", obj1);
  //Now my object can be retrieve from the JNDI context under "jndi_name"


  MyObjectImpl obj2 = (MyObjectImpl)ctx.lookup("jndi_name"); //lookup of object
  System.out.println(obj2.method(1,2)); //call 
}catch (Exception e) {
   // a failure occurred
}
```

But the call is done locally in the client JVM and not the remote JVM.

Is there any way to counter this problem?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a remote interface(using annotation @Remote) for jndi lookup.

You can see this example: http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=5532 (search for the class “CalculatorBean.java”).